MSWord for Mac search parameters in macros stay on after macros close
I have numerous macros that perform search and replace operations, some of which use optional search parameters like Match case, Use wildcards, or Ignore white-space characters. I assumed that these parameters would be used in a macro and then released when the macro is complete, but instead they carry into any searches I do by hand in the document.
Is there a way to prevent this? Is there a way to reset search parameters after a search or do I just add a do-nothing search with all the optional parameters turned off?
Thanks for your assistance.
